# StarTeam merge changes

Tags: starteam

I'm new at working with StarTeam, having previously used Subversion in projects.
In order to find out how the change packages work, I've experimented a bit - and not quite gotten the results I would've liked.

I have tried to following steps:
(I have 2 views, one called 'trunk' and one called branch1.1 which is a child of trunk)

1. trunk: Creating file TestMerge.txt with the content 'A'
2. trunk: TestMerge.Txt -> adding a new line with content 'B'
3. trunk: TestMerge.Txt -> adding a new line with content 'C'
   I go to 'Show Change Perspective' and find my 3 check-ins.

   - I select 1 and 3, right-click, advanced, View Compare/Merge.
   - I select rebase with trunk as source and branch1.1 as target.
   - Under include I select 'Selected change packages'.
   - I dont change options or properties.
   - Finish now brings up a window called 'Rebase from trunk'
   - The TestMerge.txt has merge status: Resolved, Merge Action: ignore.
   - I can only change this to 'share' (and I cannot commit if it is ignored, since nothing is changed).

When I commit these changes, branch1.1 now contains a file called TestMerge.txt - however that file contains A B and C.

I would only expect it to contain A+C, since I didn't ask for my second commit to be included in the change package.

Is that just the way StarTeam (doesn't) work or is there somewhere I can get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StarTeam does not support merging two versions of the *same file* in the *same view*,
especially not via the "*Change-Packets*" process, or the "*View Compare/Merge*" tool.

"*Change-Packets*" process and the "*View Compare/Merge*" tool are designed
for merging files and folders from different views.

(Try this with two versions of the same files that are sitting in different views.)

Comment: So what I'm trying to do, cannot be accompliced by the "tool" I'm using.

Does that mean that StarTeam is not able to do what I would like it to do? or just that there's a better way to do it?

If we assume I have two views with the same file in it.
In one view, I have made 3 changes on the file compared to the other view.
I would like to move 1 of the changes to the other view (but not all 3 changes)

Can I do that - and how?

Comment: That should be supported, but not automatically (you will have to pick the relevant changes), because 'View Compare/Merge' can't know this by himself. (to your original scenario: you will need to check-out the revisions to be merged, merge them aside, then check-in the merged file).

Comment: I dont see how that could work, if I checkout the revision '3' file, then it includes revision 2 (the B) and to get rid of that, I would have to manually edit the B out.
I thank you for your answers, I think my conclusion is that StarTeam does not support this action - even if an expert user is able to find a way to do it somehow.

Comment: I agree - StarTeam does not support merging two versions of the same file in the same view, especially not via the "Change-Packets" process. (sorry if my previous answer wasn't clear - will amend it)